# format json in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I'm trying to access a JSON version of my variable. I tried using . notation on the shows variable as I presumed it was now formatted as a json object. @shows.title but that caused an error.
I tried to use @shows.to_json.title for it to work but still no good. I thought when you format.json it already calls the to_json and that was the idea of using format or am in incorrect in thinking this way. If so what does format do then.

```
   class ShowsController < ApplicationController
      # GET /shows
      # GET /shows.json
      def index
        @shows = Show.all

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @shows }

        end
      end
```

index.html.erb

```
<p> @shows.title <p>
```

the structure I'm looking for in JSON would be like this.

```
[
                {
                    "id": "feature",
                    "width":570,
                    "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor amet emipsum do omnis iste natus",
                    "description": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantiu mdoloremque laudantium.",
                    "img": "img/work/img1.jpg",
                    "url": "http://www.bla.com"
                },
                {
                    "id": "show",
                    "width":200,
                    "title": "Lorem ipsum dolo",
                    "description": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantiu mdoloremque laudantium.",
                    "img": "img/work/img2.jpg",
                    "url": "http://www.bla.com"
                }
```

]

**UPDATED:** maybe I'm not explaining this correctly.

My goal here is to have my action in the controller call the index.html page, which it does now. On that page is a jquery plugin that requests a JSON object with all the data from the database. This way it can parse through the JSON and render all the objects on the index.html page using jquery plugin. The reason for this is it's using a plugin called jquery.masonry.js & jquery.infinitescroll.js which is now setup to use multiple JSON structures to create my pages.

Comment: to_json returns a json formatted string.  respond_to is about the output being sent to the browser, not the format of variables sent to your templates.  It seems like your trying to convert a variable to json and access that inside of an html view?

Comment: I'm trying to convert a response from the model to JSON so I can use it in my template. So what is format doing then if that's not the case. What do you mean by "output being sent to the browser". I thought that was the output fro the browser using response_to

Comment: Could I do an jquery ajax request in my index.html view for this formatted JSON then if respond_to is outputted to the browser.

Comment: You don't need to convert your model to use it in your templates, they just need to be in scope, which is accomplished by making them instance variables by using @.  Then you can access them in your html.erb like @shows.whatever.  Keeping in mind of course that shows is a collection, not your actual model class.

respond_to is a method for responding to different types of requests.  In your example you can receive a request for index.html from a browser, which wants an html formatted response. Or you may want to respond to requests for json formatted data.

Comment: Ok I get that, but what I think your not seeing from my post is when my action renders my index.html page inside that html I also need my collection from the database to be JSON formatted. This way I can use jquery to arange elements appropriately in my index.html based on the above json structure. Now whether I can do that from the model directly or I have to do another call for JSON is not what I'm understanding. All I need is my database structure to be retrieved in a JSON structure when the index.html is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your collection to be accessible to jquery, then you can render it as a json string inside of a script block.  So for example in your index.html.erb you could put:

```
<%= javascript_tag "var shows = #{@shows.to_json}" %>
```

Which will render

```
<script type="type/javascript"> var shows = { "your":"json", "object":"YAY" } </script>
```

But you still want to respond_to html

Comment: Wow this is the only way I can get the shows in the database as a json. Thanks for this.